# Hot track doesn't work in a virtual TListView while dragging

Tags: listview, delphi, debugging, delphi-2009

If I take a virtual `TListView` and try to drag items (`Accept:= True` always) the "hot tracking" system looks corrupted. In win 7 the hot item remains near the selected item, while in win 8.1 it remains fixed at random positions. 
I recorded this behavior to better understand what I mean:

[Here is the recording from win 7](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5eKWlqx_pA)

[Here is the recording from win 8.1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_dl7-ryxexs)

And this is the minimal code to reproduce the problem:

**.dfm**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 378
  ClientWidth = 398
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poScreenCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ListView1: TListView
    Left = 78
    Top = 40
    Width = 221
    Height = 286
    Columns = <
      item
        Width = 130
      end>
    DragMode = dmAutomatic
    MultiSelect = True
    OwnerData = True
    ReadOnly = True
    RowSelect = True
    TabOrder = 0
    ViewStyle = vsReport
    OnData = ListView1Data
    OnDragOver = ListView1DragOver
  end
end
```

**.pas**

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ComCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ListView1: TListView;
    procedure ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ListView1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
      State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 ListView1.Items.Count:= 10;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1Data(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 Item.Caption:= 'Item '+IntToStr(Item.Index);
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
begin
 Accept:= True;
end;

end.
```

Of course, the question is, if anything can be done to correct this behavior ?

**Edit:**

I tried to implement my own tracking system, and it seems it's working but with a little exception: the uppermost item under the cursor remains always selected...

```
function TListView.GetItemIndexAt(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
var Info: TLVHitTestInfo;
begin
 Result:= -1;
 if HandleAllocated then begin
  Info.pt:= Point(X, Y);
  Result:= ListView_HitTest(Handle, Info);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1DragOver(Sender, Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer;
  State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var Src, Dest, I: Integer;
begin
 Accept:= True;
 Src:= ListView1.Selected.Index;
 Dest:= ListView1.GetItemIndexAt(X, Y);
 for I:= 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
  if (I = Src) or (I = Dest) then ListView1.Items[I].Selected:= True
   else ListView1.Items[I].Selected:= False;
end;
```

Comment: Is the behaviour different for a non-virtual `TListView`. I ask since you specifically mentioned "virtual"

Comment: @Tom, yes, non virtual mode seems to behave correctly. Btw. it's not actually hot tracking, just the cursor highlighting which is drawn incorrectly. I would suggest using VirtualTreeView control.

Comment: Please check my answer and tell me what do you think. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by resetting the [**LVIS_DROPHILITED**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Controls/list-view-item-states) state of all items and setting this state to the just dragged over item:

```
type
  TListView = class(ComCtrls.TListView)
  protected
    procedure DragOver(Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean); override;
    procedure DoEndDrag(Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer); override;
  public
    function GetItemIndexAt(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
  end;

function TListView.GetItemIndexAt(X, Y: Integer): Integer;
var
  HitInfo: TLVHitTestInfo;
begin
  Result := -1;
  if HandleAllocated then
  begin
    HitInfo.pt := Point(X, Y);
    Result := ListView_HitTest(Handle, HitInfo);
  end;
end;

procedure TListView.DragOver(Source: TObject; X, Y: Integer; State: TDragState; var Accept: Boolean);
var
  DropIndex: Integer;
begin
  inherited;
  if OwnerData then
  begin
    ListView_SetItemState(Handle, -1, 0, LVIS_DROPHILITED);
    if Accept then
    begin
      DropIndex := GetItemIndexAt(X, Y);
      if DropIndex <> -1 then
        ListView_SetItemState(Handle, DropIndex, LVIS_DROPHILITED, LVIS_DROPHILITED);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TListView.DoEndDrag(Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  if OwnerData then
    ListView_SetItemState(Handle, -1, 0, LVIS_DROPHILITED);
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Well done! Maybe you could use the `GetItemAt` method and apply this workaround only when `OwnerData` is enabled (as it seems that non virtual mode behaves correctly).

Comment: You're welcome! I've added explanation of what is being done here and made minor changes of the code (mainly test for existing drop item; if the index is not -1, as that would include `LVIS_DROPHILITED` to all items). Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: I don't mind at all. :) I think too that testing for -1 it's a good thing, indeed, but `if OwnerData and Accept then` it's not, because all items must be cleared of `DROPHILITED` every time the `DropIndex` change. Only the `DropIndex` is conditioned by `Accept`.

Comment: Oh, that's right. I'm sorry, my mistake! Hopefully fixed :)

Comment: And by the way, thank you for correcting my explanation. I'm not English native and it's hard enough for me to write in English ;)

Comment: No worries. Me neither (I'm just using English on a daily basis) :) Your questions are well written! Just one nitpick here, it's not actually "hot tracking" which is involved here. It's just item cursor highlighting which is incorrectly rendered (most probably just because of wrong item states, which resolves this workaround).